# Spring Integration: Handle messages from Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter in parallel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

So,

if have a Spring Integration 5.5 / Spring Boot 2.7 flow that reads XML-files from a SFTP source, processes and stores them, then deletes. Things do work, but sequentially, meaning each file is processed after the other.

I'd like to do the processing and transforming asynchronously (not necessary in parallel, order is no no importance) to increase the througput. But I can't figure out, how to configure it.

The code:

```java
IntegrationFlows
  .from(Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(sftpTemplate))
  .publishSubscribeChannel(spec -> spec
    .subscribe(
      flow -> 
        flow
         .transform( /* file content to xml */ )
         .handle( /* persist as xml */ )
     )
    .subscribe(flow -> flow.handle( /* remove file */ ))
   )
  .get()
```

I guess the async / parallel handling must be defined between the source and the pub/sub-channel. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `publishSubscribeChannel()` configuration is correct and don't try to make it parallel since you cannot remove (or even close) a remote file because you deal with an `InputStream` in a payload after `Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter()`. To make it parallel from that source perspective, you need to look into a second argument of the `IntegrationFlows.from()`:

```
static IntegrationFlowBuilder from(MessageSource<?> messageSource,
        @Nullable Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> endpointConfigurer) {
```

That `Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>` gives you an access to source polling channel adapter options. One of them is `poller(Function<PollerFactory, PollerSpec> pollers)` and can be configured like:

```
e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000).taskExecutor())
```

That `taskExecutor` allows a scheduled task to be shifted to different thread. Be careful with `maxMessagesPerPoll` (`1` by default for `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`): if it is more than `1`, then that number of messages are going to be emitted in the same thread.

You also can simply have a `channel(c -> c.executor())` just after this `from()`.

Comment: ````You also can simply have a channel(c -> c.executor()) just after this from().````

The .executor() method requires arguments with Spring Integration 5.5, one of them being the Executor. I've put "Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)" here.

So, if I set maxMessagesPerPoll to 10, having 100 SFTP files to read, it should use up to 10 threads in parallel, each handling 10 files?

Comment: Well, I just gave you the pointer to that API which may help you. Of course, you need to provide an `Executor` for that channel to work properly. The `maxMessagesPerPoll` has a meaning for how much to ask the source in a single poll cycle. It is still going to produce a message for each result. All those messages are going be handed to an `ExecutorChannel`. So, with 10 threads you are going to have 10 messages in parallel, independently of the `maxMessagesPerPoll`. I suggest to look more into docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#executor-channel

Comment: and about poller: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-adapter-namespace-inbound